# How to get value from input tag from HTML

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have an input like this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="myname" id="myid" value='myvalue' />
```

How can I get myvalue from this input using HTML Agility pack?

I'm using C# and HTML Agility pack. I tried this :

```
var latlon = mydetails.DocumentNode.QuerySelector("#myname").QuerySelector("input");
```

But this didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: you should use a programming language for retreiving the value

Comment: @Edoardo I have tried with C#,  but couldn't do it.

Comment: JS / JQuery, you mentioned C#, mvc by any chance? We need more info.

Comment: you can simply use javascript @jason

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure where you want to recieve the input value but maybe this will help you if want to recieve it at server side.

Change your tag as following :
input type="hidden" runat="server" name="myname"
    id="myid" value='myvalue' />

after that you can access the variable "myid" anywhere in aspx.cs file